# How can I normalize this object using ramda or without ramda:

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I normalised response earlier to the next necessary object:

```
{
  "Medications": {
    "taskTypeGroupAlias": "Medications",
    "taskTypes": [
      "MedicationTask"
    ],
    "isReadonly": false,
    "isEnable": true,
    "shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone": true,
    "remindersNumber": 0,
    "reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes": 10,
    "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 15
  },
```

> ...and the same Measurements, Surveys, Tasks objects
>
> ...and one different object below

```
  "Visits": {
    "isReadonly": false,
    "isEnable": true,
    "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 1440
  }
}
```

The object above has already been normalized by me using ramda. I did it with next function:

```
export const formatConfig = (tasks: Tasks[], appointments: Appointments) => {
  const tasksConfig = indexBy(prop('taskTypeGroupAlias'), tasks);
  const isEnable = pathOr('', ['isEnable'], appointments);
  const reminderInAdvanceMinutes = pathOr('', ['reminderInAdvanceMinutes'], appointments);

  return {
    ...tasksConfig,
    Visits: {
      ...appointments,
      isEnable,
      reminderInAdvanceMinutes,
    },
  };
};
```

and now I have to return this object to its original form for the post request (body), like this:

```
  {
  "appointmentsConfig": {. //It's a Visits object
    "isReadonly": false,
    "isEnable": true,
    "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 1440
  },
  "tasksConfigs": [ //It's others taskTypeGroupAlias
    {
      "taskTypeGroupAlias": "Medications", 
      "taskTypes": [
        "MedicationTask"
      ],
      "isReadonly": false,
      "isEnable": true,
      "shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone": true,
      "remindersNumber": 0,
      "reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes": 10,
      "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 15
    }, ...and the same Measurements, Surveys, Tasks
    
  ]
}
```

I normalised the response earlier to the necessary object and now I need to return the old object for the post request (body). How can I do this using ramda or without ramda?

I guess i can use Object.values method, but my brain explodes when i try it))

Comment: Not sure what it is you want to do. Can you provide source and intended target data? You can log data with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2)` and copy paste from the console instead of trying to copy a logged object output.

Comment: Agreed,  Please post a small sample input object (in a usable format) and the expected output.  Also, please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i've edited the main text, please read it again